# How to use other delimiters in Perl split?

Tags: regex, perl

I can use `m!PATTERN!` if PATTERN contain  `/` chars.

Can I use this way in `split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT` as well?

Comment: How about you try it and see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The various forms of [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) are really:

- `split MATCHOP,EXPR,LIMIT`
- `split PATTERN,EXPR,LIMIT`
- `split MATCHOP,EXPR`
- `split PATTERN,EXPR`
- `split MATCHOP`
- `split PATTERN`
- `split`

Where

- `MATCHOP` is a match operator (which isn't executed when it would normally be), and
- `PATTERN` is an expression that returns one of the following:

  - A string consisting of a single space.
  - A compiled regex pattern
  - A regex pattern in string form

All ten of these are functionally equivalent:

```
$re = qr/\s+/;
$pat = '(?^u:\\s+)';

split /\s+/          Match operator
split m/\s+/         Match operator
split m!\s+!         Match operator

split qr/\s+/        Expression that returns a compiled regex pattern.
split qr!\s+!        Expression that returns a compiled regex pattern.
split $re            Expression that returns a compiled regex pattern.

split '(?^u:\s+)'    Expression that returns a stringified regex pattern.
split '(?^u:\\s+)'   Expression that returns a stringified regex pattern.
split "(?^u:\\s+)"   Expression that returns a stringified regex pattern.
split $pat           Expression that returns a stringified regex pattern.
```

Answer (score 6):

In short, the answer is yes.

Give it a try:

```
my @array = split m!/!, '1/2/3/4/5';
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont know about `m!PATTERN!`...you can use `'Pattern'`..
i.e. split('',EXPR,LIMIT)